# MVC 4 shopping cart with session passing as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, shopping-cart

I'm trying to create a shopping cart.
I'm having a problem where when I call my Session, it gets passed as null.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Courses.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ANON_Capstone.Models.Course>

@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
@section featured
{
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <h2 class="text-center">Please Login or Create an Account to make a Purchase!</h2>
        </div>
    </section>
}
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <h2><strong>Courses</strong></h2><br />
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-s-8 col-lg-4">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ShoppingCart", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <img src="~/Images/party.gif" style="width: 175px" class="img-responsive" />
                <h2>@item.className</h2>
                <p>$@item.classPrice -- @item.maxStudent spots left! </p>
                <input type="text" name="className" value="@item.className" hidden="hidden" />
                <input type="text" name="classPrice" value="@item.classPrice" hidden="hidden"  />
                <input type="text" name="classID" value="@item.ClassID" hidden="hidden" />
                <input type="hidden" name="classDesc" value="@item.classDesc" />
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Add to Shopping Cart" />
                }
            }
            <br />
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ANON_Capstone.Models;

namespace ANON_Capstone.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Courses()
    {

        return View(db.Courses.ToList());

    }

    public ActionResult ShoppingCart(string className, string classPrice, string classID, string classDesc)
    {
        Course course = new Course();
        course.className = className;
        course.classPrice = Convert.ToDouble(classPrice);
        course.ClassID = Convert.ToInt32(classID);
        course.classDesc = classDesc;
        CartModel cart = new CartModel();
        cart.course = course;
        Session["Cart"] = cart;
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

CartModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ANON_Capstone.Models
{
public class CartModel
{
    public Course course { get; set; }
}
}
```

ShoppingCart.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
}

<h2>Shopping Cart</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateCommand", "PayPal"))
{
var cart = Session["Cart"] as IEnumerable<ANON_Capstone.Models.CartModel>;
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <h2><strong>Shopping Cart</strong></h2><br />
        @if (cart != null)
        {
            <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Course Image</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Course Desc</th>
                <th>Course Price</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in cart)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="~/Images/party.gif" style="width: 175px" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                    <td>@item.course.className</td>
                    <td>@item.course.classPrice</td>
                    <td>@item.course.classDesc</td>
                </tr>
            }
            </table>
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Check Out with Paypal" />
        }

        else
        {
            <text>Your shopping cart is currently empty</text>
        }
    </div>


</div>
}
```

Comment: your Cart object has a type of CartModel not IEnumarable<CartModel>.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. Would I have to change it to var cart = new CartModel() as IEnumerable<CartModel>?

Comment: If I am not missing something, you create Cart object and add it to session in ShoppingCart action. The object has a type of `CartModel`. However, in your view you cast it to `IEnumarable<CartModel>`. I think it should be, `var cart = Session["Cart"] as CartModel`;

Comment: I tried as you've advised and now it gives me an error with the foreach loop. IT says CartModel does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator